# Arduino - I need to alter my code to insert a delay

Tags: arduino

I am running an Arduino Nano (with a RasPi to send to Thingspeak). It measures different things in my office, temp, hum, CO2 AND it waters my plant. :-)

I have a small problem with my code for the plant watering.

**Here is what I want it to do:**

```
Loop
        Measure Soil moisture
        If > 60 run pump for 2 seconds
        Delay 180 seconds (this delay goes for all sensors)
```

**I have a problem! This is what the code actually does:**

```
Loop
        Measure Soil moisture
        If > 60 run pump for 2 seconds
```

This means that it just keeps watering away, much faster than the water can absorb the water.

Please help me get the delay working.

Thank you. :-)

This is the code I am running:

```
void loop()
{
  int temp = 0, hum = 0, moist = 0, level = 0, co2_ppm = 0;
  moist = read_soil_moisture(soil_pin);
  temp = read_temp();
  hum = read_humidity();
  level = read_water_level(water_pin);//reads water level

  co2_ppm = CO2_PPM();
  //print_sensor(hum, temp, moist, level,co2_ppm);

  temp = read_temp();
  if (temp >= 3)
  {
    temp -= 3;
  }
  else
  {
    temp = 0;
  }

  log_sensor(hum, temp, moist, level, co2_ppm); //prints values of sensors to UART
  if (moist > 60)
  {

    digitalWrite(pump, LOW);//Setting relay pin high
    delay(2000);//keeps relay pin high for 2 seconds
    digitalWrite(pump, HIGH);//Setting relay pin low
  }
  else
  {

    digitalWrite(pump, HIGH);//keep relay pin low

  }
  delay(180000);//take a reading every 180 seconds
```

Github repo: https://github.com/pkold/Self-watering-plant-system

Comment: Does it never stops to pump or is the delay just less than 180 seconds? You can try to write `180000L`, so the compiler will not convert it to an int (and it likes to cast every number to int ;) )

Comment: Well what happens is that everything works fine, I get a reading every 180 seconds for all sensors. However, when the soil moisture sensor reads >60 the pump runs 2 secs, stops, runs 2 secs and so on... I stop it because the plant overflows, but i assume it will stop when the reading is <60 again...

Comment: why do your comments say HIGH when you set the outputs LOW and vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have readings from the moisture sensor when it is complete dry and when it is fully emerged in water?
When i look at your github repo the moisture value is a percentage which increase when the moisture rises.
Turning on the pump when the moisture is already above 60 will only increase the sensor value.

Comment: Hey Fred, I use the Grove sensor and it reads high when dry and low when moist. Actually it all works great now. :-) You can check out the readings here. Thank you for engaging.